# Is there a better way to debug a code in salesforce?

Tags: apex, force.com, debugging

I have been working on test classes and often writing test scenarios for code developed by other developers. Many a time i would need to insert in some debug statements to understand the flow of the code or to identify what is causing the failures of asserts.

I currently run the test class using the Apex Test Execution under Develop and check the debug logs under Administration setup -> monitoring.

I find this method a lot time consuming with the no of clicks needed to get to the logs. Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: See this post. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275/how-to-export-debug-logs/280#280

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are ways to export the debug logs to remote programs like the one posted in the comment above.

However, you should use the *developer console* rather than the 'Setup->Monitoring' for faster execution of individual methods and debugging test methods when they're actually running.

Also, for more technical examples see:
[How to export debug logs?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275/how-to-export-debug-logs/280#280)

Comment: Thanks jordan .. Will take a look at FuseIT.. Developer console seems to freeze up many a times for me

Comment: Which browser are you using? It seems to be more reliable in some that others. The Heap Dumps are by far the best way of debugging apex code these days.

Comment: FireFox on windows

Comment: I use a simple tool which streams logs to browser window, Extremely productive and customizable.
All you need is add a logger class in your salesforce environment and call
Restlogger.debug('logname', JSON.serialize(data'));

And subscribe for logs using Salesforce login Username..
Bammm that's all

https://github.com/gs-akhan/salesforce-debugger